# labeling pie chart -- between radial center and radial outer

Tags: plotting, graphics

is there a way to put the labels on this pie chart (e.g. {"c1", "c2", "c3"}) at a distance from the origin on the slices between "RadialCenter" and "RadialOuter"?
E.g. is there a way to tune the precise location of the location of ChartLabels by specifying some distance from the origin? I considered attempting to use `Placed` , but for pie charts in Mathematical it [looks like there are only three options](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Placed.html).

```
PieChart[{{1, 2, 3}}, 
 ChartLabels -> {Placed[{"c1", "c2", "c3"}, "RadialOuter"]}, 
 SectorSpacing -> 0.5]
```

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can post-process the output of `PieChart` to change the positions of `Text` objects:

```
{ro, rc} = PieChart[{{1, 2, 3}}, 
      ChartLabels -> {Placed[{"c1", "c2", "c3"}, #]}, 
      SectorSpacing -> 0.5, ImageSize -> 300, PlotLabel -> #] & /@ 
   {"RadialOuter", "RadialCenter"};

Row[{ro, rc}]
```

[image]

```
{radiuso, radiusc} = First@Cases[#, Text[_, p_, ___] :> Norm[p], All] & /@ {ro, rc}
```

> ```
>  {0.9, 0.666667}
> ```

```
rm = Show[rc /. Text[t_, p_, x___] :> 
    Text[t, Mean[{radiuso, radiusc}] Normalize[p], x], 
  PlotLabel -> "mean(RadialCenter,RadialOuter)"]
```

[image]

```
epilog = {Blue, Circle[{0, 0}, Mean[{radiuso, radiusc}]], Red, 
   Circle[{0, 0}, radiuso], Green, Circle[{0, 0}, radiusc]};

Row[Show[#, Epilog -> epilog] & /@ {ro, rc, rm}]
```

[image]

Using `Manipulate` to interactively control the radial positions of labels:

```
symbolicpositions = {"RadialInner", "RadialInside", "RadialCenter", 
   "RadialOuter", "RadialEdge", "RadialOutside"};

radii = First @ Cases[PieChart[{1}, ChartLabels -> Placed[{"c1"}, #]], 
      Text[_, p_, ___] :> Norm[p], All] & /@ symbolicpositions;

Manipulate[Legended[Show[
   rc /. Text[t_, p_, x___] :> Text[t, radius Normalize[p], x], 
   ImageSize -> 500, PlotLabel -> None, 
   PlotRange -> {3/{-2, 2}, 3/{-2, 2}}, 
   Epilog -> {Green, Circle[{0, 0}, radiusc], Blue, 
     Circle[{0, 0}, radiuso], Thick, Red, Circle[{0, 0}, radius]}], 
  LineLegend[{Green, Blue}, {"RadialCenter", "RadialOutside"}]], 
 Row[{"radius", 
   Column[{Control @ {{radius, Mean[{radiuso, radiusc}], ""}, 
       Thread[radii -> symbolicpositions], ControlType -> SetterBar}, 
     Control @ {{radius, Mean[{radiuso, radiusc}], ""}, 0, 2, 
       Appearance -> "Labeled", ImageSize -> Large}}]}], 
 Alignment -> Center]
```

[image]